# Windows 7 keyboard shortcut Windows Key + D doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

For some unknown reason, the shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> stopped working.

All the others still work, like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open up the Explorer, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to minimize all the windows and so on.

Any ideas why this happens with this shortcut in specific? I have googled it up, but haven't found anyone with similar problem.

I am using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Comment: Does clicking the button in the bottom right corner of your screen work?

Comment: Right now it doesn't. But it comes and goes. When I first posted this question it did work, but now it doesn't. I haven't messed with any configurations whatsoever.

Comment: Does it work after a reboot?

Comment: Check to see if you have a display control panel installed. Does anything else come up when you use [Winkey]+D?

Comment: Are you debugging in VS? For me when I debug WIN+D sometimes stops working (especially when a break point is hit)

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [@liquidplace's answer](https://superuser.com/q/298921/150988#537071):
Kill and restart explorer.exe in Task Manager.

Five simple steps:

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to invoke Task Manager.
2. Select: Processes" [if you have Windows 7]
   or "Details" [if you have Windows 10].
3. Scroll down and select  "explorer.exe" and then select: "End task".
4. Click on "File" and then "Run new task".
5. Type in "explorer.exe" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Had exactly the same symptoms;
all Win hotkeys worked except <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. 
It occurred after messing with AutoHotKey, but that is probably unrelated since neither <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> nor the "Show desktop" button next to the taskbar clock worked.

Answer (score 2):

It may sound strange but since i've come across the same glitch twice, i'm pretty sure the problem stops after.. **updating Adobe Flash**. In fact, after solving this peculiar case myself, i've found a couple users complaining about it, [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/show-desktop-button-and-windowsd-shortcut-not/a2d87849-39e5-4ecd-bdbb-d6b8862d54ea).

I bet there's a *miscoordination* (sic!) of adobe's automatic update window with dwm.exe. Once i've killed "explorer.exe" process and adobe's automatic updater came up! Next time i've just updated adobe flash using Start-->Control Panel--> "Flash Player". You may also update Adobe Flash Player thru the official [link](http://get2.adobe.com/flashplayer/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a  2-in-1 laptop + tablet combo, then the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> shortcut could also stop working because you're accidentally still in tablet mode.

Try putting your 2-in-1 back into tablet mode by flipping the screen, then exit tablet mode by flipping it back. <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will start working again.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and just now fixed it by installing an Adobe Acrobat Reader update, which was sitting on my tray notification.